# Can i use different CSR for APNS and In-House distribution certificate for Push Notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, swift5, apple-developer

I'm facing one issue while enabling Push Notification for our Enterprise application. I can not create new In-house certificate as it is already created by anyone else in the enterprise for other application and there is no more limit to create new one. So i have to reuse it for my requirement.

I can create my APNS certificate but CSR will be different from one used for creating In-House certificate. I have tested notification and its not working. Is it because of this or any other reason.

**In short**: Will there be any issue if CSR used to create APNS certificate is different from CSR used to create In-house distribution certificate used to sign the app. Please note: Selected AppID is same for both.

Answer (score 0):

I tested above scenario and its is working. So answer is yes we can use different CSR for In-House and APNS certificate. Bundle Id used should be same for both certificate.